# ¿[ao] es lo mismo que (a|o)? Expresiones regulares

Tags: regex, ruby

Estoy estudiando las expresiones regulares, me he dado cuenta de que `perr[ao]` y `perr(a|o)` son equivalentes.

Aquí viene mi duda (que seguramente sea una chorrada), ¿no hay ninguna diferencia al respecto? Es decir, por escribir menos, ¿podría utilizar `perr[ao]`?
Supongo que hacer esto, por corto que sea no es ni semántico ni buena práctica.

¿Qué opináis?

Ya sé que es diferente aplicar (a|o) a [ao] (para casos diferentes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El operador alterno de pipa `|` recorrerá el texto 2 veces si la expresión de la derecha no se cumple lo que lo hará un poquito mas lento. Mientras que la expresión de texto literal `[]` simplemente comprobara si por lo menos 1 carácter esta presente en el texto.